# Dotless j in Times New Roman

Tags: fonts, times

I'm trying to add a dotless j and get a black box.

```
\documentclass[openany,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
% index options
% \makeindex[options=-s dots,intoc]
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}\j\end{document}
```

How do I get the dotless j?

Comment: If you remove `\usepackage{mathptmx}` you get it. (I am not saying this is a real solution, but if you try `$\jmath$` with  `\usepackage{mathptmx}` you even get an error.)

Comment: `mathptmx` is one of an old font package, please switch to `txfonts` is advisable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please switch to `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` will solve the issue,

If still you want to use `mathptmx`, then the below code may helps you:

```
\documentclass[openany,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
% index options
% \makeindex[options=-s dots,intoc]
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dotlessj}
\begin{document}
\j\quad j

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`, instead of `txfonts`

Comment: @egreg oops..sorry, I'll update myself...and thanks a lot...

Comment: So I guess it was just me being dumb with my packages...